# How to scroll text of textview inside a Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a Gridveiew.In the getView of GridView i pass , a RelativeLayout(contains image view and textview as its children). I want the text of textview to scroll horizontally as its too long. 
this is my xml. but textview does not scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="false">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/theme_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/theme_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theme_preview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried android:clickable="false" for your relative layout.

Comment: you can wrap your relative layout with HorixzontalScrollView(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add [this attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ascrollHorizontally) to your [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html):

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Or, if you want to do it in code:

```
textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

Comment: Hi ariefbayu, thanks for the reply but its not working here is my xml file that i inflate in grid getview.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Using this,   



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:clickable="false">


                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/theme_preview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
     <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/theme_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/theme_preview"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The HorizontalScrollView will scroll entire relativeLayout. But my functionality is different. My gridview is positioned correctly. I want the text of textivew to scroll horizontally.

Comment: i have edited my answer, you just put text view inside HorizontalScrollView, which should work and match your requirements

Comment: i surrounded textview with HorizontalScrollView but still not working :( and i am loosing onItemClick functionality on my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_image"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your GridView adapter class set your textview.setSelected(true)

```
 holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text); 
 holder.txtTitle.setSelected(true);
```